# How to invisible a word?

Tags: java, html, swing

I need to invisible a word in this html code. , this is not working. can anyone suggest me a good method

```
 JLabel[] label;
    GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(0, 2);
    panel.setLayout(experimentLayout);
    label = new JLabel[100];
    label[0] = new JLabel("<html><body>\n"
            + "<table width=\"45\" border=\"1\">\n"
            + " <tr>\n"
            + "   <td height=\"63\">Name</td>\n"
            + " </tr>\n"
            + " <tr>\n"
            + "   <td height=\"63\"><div style=\"visibility: hidden\">id</div></td>\n"
            + " </tr>\n"
            + "</table>"
            + "</body></html>");
    panel.add(label[0]);
    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
```

Comment: Have you put the html in a file and tried it in a browser?  Curious why you are mixing languages.

Comment: @JamesBlack Because Java/Swing is capable of rendering HTML

Comment: Swing may not support the visibility style. You can have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html) for a list of supported styles

Comment: have you tried with style="display:none"

Comment: @SpringLearner according to the JavaDocs, that may not be supported

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am not that much strong in swing, my sugesstion is simple CSS

Comment: Another way to hide a text: style="text-indent:-1000;"

Comment: style="text-indent:-1000; worked. Thanks for the support.